# Integer array column having more than one value

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, aggregate-functions, postgresql-9.6

This column is an integer array type:

```sql
log_session
-----------------------
 {105683,105694}
 {111833}
 {120285}
 {108592}
 {84659,84663}
```

I want to know how many `log_session` have just 1 value (3 in this case), and how many have more than 1 value (2 here).

**EDIT**:

```sql
select 
    count(*) filter(where array_length(log_session, 1) = 1) as cnt_length_1,
    count(*) filter(where array_length(log_session, 1) > 1) as cnt_length_more_than_1
from mytable;

ERROR:  function array_length(integer[]) does not exist
LINE 2:     count(*) filter(where array_length(log_session) = 1) as ...
                                  ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

select version();
                                                               version                                                               
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 PostgreSQL 9.6.20 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (Ubuntu 9.6.20-1.pgdg18.04+1), compiled by gcc (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04) 7.5.0, 64-bit
(1 row)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`array_length`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-array.html):

```
select 
    count(*) filter(where array_length(log_session, 1) = 1) as cnt_length_1,
    count(*) filter(where array_length(log_session, 1) > 1) as cnt_length_more_than_1
from mytable
```

| cnt_length_1 | cnt_length_more_than_1 |
| --- | --- |
| 3 | 2 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/4vftQQU3)

Comment: Ah, I guess this fuction is only available in recent versions of PGSQL. Currently I have access to a remote, older version `PostgreSQL 9.6.20 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu`.

Comment: HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

Comment: @arilwan: `array_length` was already available in version 9.6: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/functions-array.html. However, the `filter` clause of aggregate funtions such as `count()` was not. Probably you need to rephrase the counts, as in: `sum(case when array_length(log_session, 1) = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as cnt_length_1`

Comment: `CASE`-based `filter` clause emulation should work too, but it shouldn't be necessary as `filter` support [reaches all the way back to 9.4](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/release/9.4.0/#AEN124521). OP's [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/75815373/3) isn't a clean paste because it first shows a copy of your (correct) code, but then the error message suggests they skipped the [`array_length(anyarray, int)`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/functions-array.html#ARRAY-FUNCTIONS-TABLE) second argument (dimension) when they ran it: "`filter(where array_length(log_session) = 1)`".